# Creating CSS3 Animated Gradient Background

Tags: html, css, animation, gradient

I want to create output as a horizontal rectangle size animation ,it should not cover whole page,I am searching online but unable to find solution, kindly help me. Many thanks. I want output like below:

[image]

```css
.heading {
 width: 100wh; 
 height: 90vh;
 color: #fff;
 background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #EE7752, #E73C7E, #23A6D5, #23D5AB);
 background-size: 200% 200%;
 -webkit-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
 -moz-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
 animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
    }

   
    @keyframes Gradient {
 0% {
  background-position: 0% 50%
 }
 50% {
  background-position: 100% 50%
 }
 100% {
  background-position: 0% 50%
 }
    }
```

```html
<head>
    <title>Pure CSS3 Gradient Background Animation</title>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="abc.css">  
</head>

<body>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
    family=Open+Sans:300" type="text/css" />

    <div class="heading">Pure CSS3 Animated Gradient Background</div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: If you do not want it to cover the entire page, simply change the `height: 90vh;` to a smaller value, say `height: 100px;`

Comment: simply remove width/height and add padding: https://jsfiddle.net/bko5a1sv/

Comment: ok thanks a lot ...I am trying with ur code

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks a lot it served my purpose

Comment: @AustenHolland ok ya I got it

Comment: @TemaniAfif how can I put text content to center ? I tried with "display: inline-block its resizing the animation div to smaller size from left so I put width:100% still text contents are not coming to center, please help me

Comment: add `text-align:center`

Comment: just one doubt in css file this codes are removed will it create any problem in other browsers like mozilla opera : @-webkit-keyframes gradFade {
  0%,
  100% {
    background-position: 0 50%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes gradFade {
  0%,
  100% {
    background-position: 0 50%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
  }
}

Comment: we no more need such code, vendor prefixes are no more need for animation

Comment: ok...I got it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some keyframes and a basic div tag you can customize this easily. Use z-index to position where you would like.

To control the height you can wrap the gradient in a relative div and control the height separately using CSS.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes gradFade {
  0%,
  100% {
    background-position: 0 50%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes gradFade {
  0%,
  100% {
    background-position: 0 50%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
  }
}

@keyframes gradFade {
  0%,
  100% {
    background-position: 0 50%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
  }
}

.custom-container {
  height: 50vh;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.bg-overlay {
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, #fd03d2, #fd4703, #fded03, #03f0fd);
  background-size: 400%;
  -webkit-animation: gradFade 20s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: gradFade 20s ease infinite;
  animation: gradFade 20s ease infinite;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-container">
  <div class="bg-overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for the answer, Instead of using  "position : absolute" because it varies browser to browser and position does not come same in mobile view and in desktop view, any alternative for replacing this line?

Comment: You can remove it, see my answer

Comment: ok thanks ...upvoted and accepting ur ans... just one doubt , just below this animation div there is occuring extra space due to which my contents are going down..is there any height of extra space that I can remove?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but if I am understanding correctly you can subtract the pixel values like this: `height: calc(50vh - 75px);`

Comment: Or add a negative margin: `margin-top: -75px;` to move the div up

Comment: it will overflow if I resize the browser

Comment: Try adding `overflow: hidden;`? Try controlling the outside div and add your code to a wrapper to slice/crop the gradient